# Filtering BindingList

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, bindinglist

In C# WinForms I have two DataGrids displaying tabular data. First display all rows, second one is supposed to display filtered set of these rows. I need to build filtered view on my BindingList view instance. This view needs to be updated, once underlying list is changed.

I've tried to build new BindingList instance with LINQ and Where
but the filtered is not updated when underlying myList is changed.

```
var filtered = new BindingList<Clip>(myList.Where<Clip>
(
c => c.participant.Contains(id)
).ToList<Clip>());
```

How can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560365/filter-bindingsource-when-datasource-is-a-bindinglist

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940504/binding-datagridview-to-bindinglist-and-filter-rows-by-textbox

Comment: both are kind of similar questions

Comment: you aren't binding it to the underlying list - you're creating a *new* list with the `Where`+`ToList`, and binding to that, so no: it won't ever be updated - the only thing that can see this new list is : the binding-list

Comment: So is there any way to have two synchronized grids? one with all data, second with filtered ? Once the row is added to first grid, the second one display it if criteria is matched.

Answer (score 3):

`BindingList<T>` doesn't support filtering (not directly, at least), so I propose to substitute your BindingList with a DataTable. [DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview) supports filtering and the filtered data is just a custom subset of the same DataTable.

In the example, two [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource) classes are use to bind the same DataTable to two DataGridView controls.
One of the BindingSource class is bound to a filtered DataView of the DataTable, using the [DataView.RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter) property, an [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression) which accepts a subset of SQL-like commands.

Here, the second `DataGridView.DataSource` is set to the BindingSource that has its DataSource linked to the filtered `DataView`.
The filter is defined using a specific value (`"Value A1"`) of the second Column (`Column1`).

You can see in the visual sample that the two DataGridView control update their cells values when the cells' values of both the DataGridViews are changed.
Also, the filter is active on the second DataGridView: the rows are filtered when the filtered Column(s) values change.

[image: DataGridView filtered BindingSource]

To test this behaviour, add 2 DataGridView controls to a Form, add a Button (here, named `btnBind`) and subscribe to the `Click` event with the **`btnBind_Click`** handler.

```
private BindingSource dgvBindingSource1 = null;
private BindingSource dgvBindingSource2 = null;
private DataTable dt = null;

private void btnBind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FillData(3, 3);
    dgvBindingSource1 = new BindingSource(dt, null);

    DataView dv = dt.AsDataView();
    dv.RowFilter = "Column1 = 'Value A1'";
    dgvBindingSource2 = new BindingSource(dv, null);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dgvBindingSource1;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = dgvBindingSource2;
}

private void FillData(int cols, int rows)
{
    dt = new DataTable("TestTable");
    dt.Columns.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, cols)
              .Select(i => new DataColumn("Column" + i.ToString(), typeof(string))).ToArray());

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        dt.Rows.Add(Enumerable.Range(0, cols)
               .Select(n => $"Value {(char)('A' + r)}" + n.ToString()).ToArray());
    }
}
```