# Adding Lots of Columns to DataTable In a Non-List Way?

Tags: vb.net

I have a DataTable I need to hold some calculated factors in, I wish to hold this in a table, then move it all into a DataSet for the 4 seperate results to then export to XML for logging purposes.

I have 74 columns, now I I've done the standard of 
`dt.Columns.Add("Column",GetType("Etc"))` however the fact I have 74 columns makes it unsightly in my mind and just adds lots of lines to my code.

Is there a better way of doing this without adding shedloads of lines to my code?

Comment: Well, you can use the `dt.Columns.AddRange()` method. If you have a `Dictionary<string, string>` with names/types pairs, you can use `Enumerable.Range(0, [NumberOfColumnsToAdd])` and `.Select` the pairs using the provided indexer. If you don't care too much about the column's name and the type is the same or irrelevant (cast later to a specific type), you don't need the Dictionary; you can set the Column's name using the indexer (`"Column" + i.ToString()`).

Comment: I mean, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55748948/7444103), where you use `Type.GetTpe("System.[Type]")` instead of `typeof([Type])`.